# What does this for statement do?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm working on hash table codes on *C* language from my lecturer. There are 2 for that I've never seen before:

```
for(;t!=NULL;t=t->next)
```

and

```
for(;*s;s++)
```

well it's not like an ordinary for I've known before:

```
for(value first; value last; value ++ / --)
```

please kindly provide working example of those for.

Comment: Basically take your pointer `t`, and keep moving through `t->next` until you get a pointer that points to `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(;t!=NULL;t=t->next)
```

This loop means you have decleared and initialised t somewhere, so you don't need to initialise again.

```
for(;*s;s++)
```

This loop exactly does the same except the terminating condition. The value of `*s` should be zero for the loop to terminate.

Actually the syntax of for loop is:

```
for(initialization;boolean_condition;updation)
```

**Any field can be left empty** and if the boolean condition is false in some step the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

For loop is

```
for(INIT; COND; AFTERTHOUGHT) {
    CODE
}
```

`INIT` block runs only once at start of the loop

`COND` block runs after each iteration and check one need to continue this loop or not

`AFTERTHOUGHT` blocks runs after each iteration to update some values like counters

In your case

```
for(;t!=NULL;t=t->next)
```

There is no INIT block. Seems like it was done before this loop like

```
Node *t = pointerToRootNode;
for(; t!=NULL; t=t->next) {
   // deal with t->data i guess
}
```

In second case

```
for(;*s;s++)
```

Also there is no `INIT` block. In `COND` block just dereferencing `s` pointer. Look at this example.

```
const char* some_str = "ab";
char* s = some_str;
if (*s) {
    puts("It will be printed")
    s++;
}
if (*s) {
    puts("It will be printed too");
    s++;
}
if (*s) {
    puts("It will never be printed because *s == 0 i.e end of string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one iterates through a linked list until it reaches the very end, which is the place you could add the next node.

The second one does a similar concept, except it's looking for a value of zero when it dereferences the pointer.

Comment: The second one checks the content of the pointer, not the pointer. It would be useful for iterating over a zero-terminated string. Also, if you are adding a new node to a linked list, you would normally prefer to put at the the beginning because that's faster than walking through the whole thing.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe thanks for the clarification. You are correct about the second entry, of course. I also concur it would be smarter to insert a node in a linked list at the beginning, but there are plenty of cases where inserting it at the end makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;t!=NULL;t=t->next) or for(;*s;s++)
```

=> the initial condition is not required (assuming t is declared somewhere else)

```
for(int i = 10; i > 0 ; i --)
```

=> `int i = 0; for (; i > 0; i--)`